# I want to build an ADC with an ADS 131M02

Tags: adc

I need to convert analog inputs to digital outputs with an ADS131M02. I drew a circuit with what I saw and read. Is it correct? Do I need to use any circuit element besides the [ADS131M02](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m02.pdf?ts=1674735741521&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the section of the data sheet that refers to interfacing?

Comment: I've read, but I'm new to electronics @Andyaka

Comment: So, what device do you need to acquire the digital value of the analogue sample? Showing terminals for an analogue input is no good without terminals for analogue ground.

Comment: I need ADS131M02, I didnt understand

Comment: Where does the digital value go? What does it connect to?

Comment: I connected it to the legs 12, 14, 15 and 16 you see in the schematic.I'm asking if I'm right or wrong in this schematic

Comment: But, where do those connections connect to?

Comment: ESP32 S3 DEVKİT

Comment: What actual pins on the Dev kit